# PHP-FPM triggers "pm.max_children" but does never recover

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a scenario where I use some JQuery (yes a very old project) that does 10~100 HTTP GET requests async. I just fire them and let the browser handle how many are being done in parallel. I don't care about the performance, the call is quick.

However only a few calls finish, the rest will get a 504 Gateway timeout from Nginx after about a minute. After that "nothing" works (it all gets a timeout).

The php-fpm logs contains:

```
2023-09-20T14:42:16.773528255Z [20-Sep-2023 14:42:16] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

Sure, that is 5 per default (local development). Ofc I can change that to 100, or 1000 but I don't really want that. I want the requests to either wait or terminate or timeout but not "crash" php-fpm.

For the php-fpm we use docker `php:php-8.1-fpm-alpine`. We do install a few extensions (amqp, gd, imagick, memcached, opcache, xdebug and a few others`. If needed I can retry/rewrite things to be able to test this in a "clean" environment. The PHP config is the default one. I do NOT have a` www.conf` file for the pool (so that is also just default).

docker-compose.yaml

```
  phpfpm:
    image: our-own-registry
    ports:
      - 9000
    environment:
      xx: xx
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project
      - ./cachegrinds/:/tmp/cachegrinds
  nginx:
    image: our-own-registry
    volumes:
      - ./config/docker-nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./css:/opt/project/css
      - ./js:/opt/project/js
      - ./images:/opt/project/images
      - ./font:/opt/project/font
    ports:
      - 8880:80
      - 8443:443
    links:
      - phpfpm
```

General idea of the nginx config (I can post it al if needed)

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen *:443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name xx;

  root /opt/project;

    location /
      {
      client_max_body_size 10M;
      rewrite .* /dispatch.php break;

      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }
```

My javascript code is very simple:

```
        $(".remove-checkbox:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
            $.get("file.php?action=xx, function () {
                console.log("ok");
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log("fail");
            })
        });
```

The first possible entrypoint (in our case: `dispatch.php`) has on line 1 a `die("test")` so no real code is executed.

So: I click my button, I fire 100 http requests (100 checkboxes in this case). I see in my browser that 2~4 succeed (HTTP 200 with "test" as reply). All others are stuck on pending and after a minute get a HTTP 504 from nginx. I waited 10 minutes but even after that time I still cannot do anything else. Any page load / refresh will result in a 504 after a minute.

I need to restart my php-fpm in order to get it workin again.

For reference (after the issue happened):

```
/var/www/html # ps auxf
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
    6 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
    7 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
    8 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
    9 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
   10 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
   11 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   17 root      0:00 ps auxf
```

So my question:
Is it not expected for the results to either be "slow" but finish, or terminate/timeout? But then the php-fpm should still work? Or is this somehow expected?